# Проверка xml файла согласно схемы.xsd. C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Как правильно должен выглядеть "MarksType" из этой схемы:

```
<complexType name="StudentType">
    <sequence>
      <element name="Name" type="string" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <element name="Age" type="byte" maxOccurs="110"/>
      <element name="Marks" type="tns:MarksType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
```

Если он представлен вот так в .xml документе:

```
<Marks>
  <int>2</int>
  <int>8</int>
</Marks>
```

Пробовал так:

```
  <simpleType name="MarksType">
    <restriction base="int">
      <maxExclusive value="11"/>
      <minExclusive value="0"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>
```

но это не правильно.

Comment: Имя элемента пишется в `element/@name`, а имя типа тут вообще ни при чём.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я спросил какова должна быть структура типа "MarksType". Немного не понял о чем вы мне сказали

Comment: я говорю, откуда у вас взялась идея использовать restriction? И зачем вы вообще используете simpleType для составного элемента?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov так в том-то и вопрос, что я не знаю как именно должна в этом случае выглядеть структура этого типа и именно это я спрашиваю.

Comment: Вы уже написали StudentType. Значит, вы знаете как писать такие типы...

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov знаю как писать некоторые типы, но конкретно в случае MarksType я не совсем понимаю как должна выглядеть структура этого типа, с учётом того, что я хотел проверять каждое значение int на правильность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Структура типа, которая требовалась мне:

```
<complexType name="StudentType">
    <sequence>
      <element name="Name" type="string" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <element name="Age" type="tns:AgeType" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <element name="Marks">
        <complexType>
          <sequence>
            <element name="int" type="tns:MarkType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/> 
          </sequence>
        </complexType>
      </element>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <simpleType name="AgeType">
    <restriction base="byte">
      <minExclusive value="15"/>
      <maxExclusive value="110"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="MarkType">
    <restriction base="int">
      <minInclusive value="1"/>
      <maxInclusive value="10"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>
```